# html table and populate with php with empty rows

Tags: php, html

I am trying to fill table with data.
I want to achieve something that looks like [image]

However, my result is:

[image]

I guess this might be related to the php IF-statement.

Here is my code:

```
<table class="tg">
    <tr>
        <th class="tg-s6z2" colspan="2" rowspan="4">OPPONENT</th>
        <th class="tg-s6z2" colspan="5">DIVISION</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tg-s6z2" colspan="5">TEAM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <?php  
        foreach($rows as $row) {
            echo "<td class='tg-031e' colspan='2'>";
            echo $row["Date"];
            echo "</td>";
        }           
        ?>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tr>
    <?php  
        foreach($rows as $row) {
            echo"<tr>";
            echo "<td class='tg-031e' colspan='2'>";
            echo $row["teamName"];
            echo "</td>";

            if(!empty($row["Score"])){
                echo"<td>";
                echo$row["Score"];  
                echo "</td>";
            }else{
                echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
            }
            echo"</tr>";
        }           
    ?>  
</table>
```

THE OUTPUT OF `$results`

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [Date] => 2015-04-22 
        [0] => 2015-04-22 
        [Score] => 1:4 
        [1] => 1:4 
        [divisionID] => 2 
        [2] => 2 
        [3] => 2 
        [teamName] => TEAM YXZ 
        [4] => TEAM XYZ ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [Date] => 2015-04-15 
        [0] => 2015-04-15 
        [Score] => 2.5:2.5 
        [1] => 2.5:2.5 
        [divisionID] => 2 
        [2] => 2 
        [3] => 2 
        [teamName] =>  TEAM XYZ 'B' 
        [4] => TEAM XYZ 'B' 
    ) 
)
```

Comment: Can you show us the contents of `$rows`?

Comment: in $ rows is everything that sql returned form database (all selected fields as follow score team name and date)

Comment: We must see the structure of `$rows` in order to fabricate an exact answer. Somehow you need to tie the scores to the appropriate date.

Comment: Run this above your `table` tag: `echo '<pre>'; print_r($rows); echo '</pre>';` then copy-paste the output in your question.

Comment: ok the content of $ rows is at the bottom any clues now ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop over the dates of the column headings, checking whether the current element of `$rows` matches the corresponding date. First make an array of all the dates when you're creating the headings:

```
    $dates = array();
    foreach($rows as $row) {
        echo "<td class='tg-031e' colspan='2'>";
        echo $row["Date"];
        $dates[] = $row['Date'];
        echo "</td>";
    }
```

Then when you write the rows, loop through the dates. When it matches, write the score, otherwise leave the `<td>` empty (there's no need to write `&nbsp;`).

```
    foreach($rows as $row) {
        echo"<tr>";
        echo "<td class='tg-031e' colspan='2'>";
        echo $row["teamName"];
        echo "</td>";
        foreach ($dates as $date) {
            echo "<td>";
            if ($row['Date'] == $date && !empty($row['Score'])) {
                echo $row["Score"];
            }
            echo "</td>";
        }
        echo"</tr>";
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your answer Barmar now I understand how to manage it

Answer (score 0):

Your conditional statement checking `$row['score']` is saying add a `TD` with a score or add a `TD` with nothing.  You still need to add a `TD` regardless if it's blank or not or it will break the table layout.

Also, the data you get back, is it enough data for the loop to fill out the whole table?  It seems to me that there is something going on with the data being returned along with the conditional statement.

Answer (score 0):

The example image you gave is not corresponding with the data `$rows` has. The match on `2015-04-22` should have the score `1:4` right?

I've separated the logic from the HTML.

In my opinion, the way `$rows` is constructed is generally bad design.

With that in mind; here's what I've came up with;

```
<?php

$dates = array();
foreach ($rows as $row):
    $dates[] = $row['Date'];
endforeach;

$matches = array();
foreach ($rows as $row):
    $scores = array();
    foreach ($dates as $date):
        $score = '';
        if (!empty($row['Score']) && $row['Date'] === $date):
            $score = $row['Score'];
        endif;
        $scores[] = $score;
    endforeach;
    $matches[] = array('teamName' => $row['teamName'], 'Scores' => $scores);
endforeach;
?>

<table class="tg">
    <tr>
        <th class="tg-s6z2" colspan="2" rowspan="4">OPPONENT</th>
        <th class="tg-s6z2" colspan="5">DIVISION</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tg-s6z2" colspan="5">TEAM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <?php foreach ($dates as $date): ?>
            <td>
                <?php echo $date; ?>
            </td>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($matches as $match): ?>
        <tr>
            <td class="tg-031e" colspan="2">
                <?php echo $match['teamName']; ?>
            </td>
            <?php foreach ($match['Scores'] as $score): ?>
                <td><?php echo $score; ?></td>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer vonUbisch now I understand how to manage it

Comment: If an answer has helped you get to your solution, accept it as your answer to this question.